# Filling in Gaps in SQL when I have multiple records per day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of rates that looks like this.

```
rate_date | rate_num | fxd_code | var_code | ratecode |   rate   
01/01/Jan |    1     |   USD    |   EUR    |   CASH   |  1.24569  
01/01/Jan |    1     |   USD    |   EUR    |   TRF    |  1.28795  
01/01/Jan |    2     |   USD    |   EUR    |   CASH   |  1.28795  
01/01/Jan |    1     |   USD    |   GBP    |   CASH   |  1.24569  
01/01/Jan |    1     |   USD    |   EUR    |   CASH   |  1.24569
```

For each day there are two rates per unique `fxd_code`, `var_code` and `ratecode` combination. These rates are distinguished by the `rate_num` column.

For some days, there are no rates in the table. What I want to do is to fill in missing dates with the most recent available day in the table. I have found some queries that do this for single distinguishing parameters but I need one that can select the most recent considering the `rate_num`, `fxd_code`, `var_code` and `ratecode`.

Help will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The ```fill``` tag is incorrectly placed. Please remove it and assign a correct tag for the database you are using. Also, you say you have a query to do this and you basically want to tweak it to your requirement I assume. Can you share that query as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using Oracle. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean that the *rows* are missing from the table.  I think a recursive CTE is a pretty easy method for putting this together.

Here is what the code looks like in Oracle:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select rate_date, rate_num, fxd_code, var_code, ratecode, max(rate_date) over () as max_rate_date
      from test
      union all
      select rate_date + interval '1' day, rate_num, fxd_code, var_code, ratecode, max_rate_date
      from cte
      where not exists (select 1
                        from test t
                        where t.rate_date = cte.rate_date + interval '1' day and
                              t.rate_num = cte.rate_num and
                              t.fxd_code = cte.fxd_code and
                              t.var_code = cte.var_code and
                              t.ratecode = cte.ratecode
                       ) and
            cte.rate_date < cte.max_rate_date
     )
select *
from cte
order by rate_date, rate_num, fxd_code, var_code, ratecode;
```

Most databases support recursive CTEs.  However, date functions differ.  The syntax might be a bit different on your database.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5a588027afb252634acecd1640ddc166) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon. Tried this and got an error though.  ORA-32039: recursive WITH clause must have column alias list
32039. 00000 -  "recursive WITH clause must have column alias list"
*Cause:    A WITH clause query referred to itself (recursive) but did
           not have a column alias list specified for it.
*Action:   Add a column alias list for the WITH clause query name.

Comment: I am using Oracle 11g. I fixed the ORA-32039 error. But now i am getting issues with DATEADD. I feel like this is almost there. Can you help please

Comment: @jeydee . . . I adjusted the syntax for Oracle.

Comment: Thanks @gordon-linoff. Almost there. Now i get a different error. Tried with the fiddle. Got the same error. ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 16. Please help sir!

Comment: @jeydee . . . Oracle 11 doesn't support recursive CTEs.  You have to use `connect by`.

Comment: Thanks! Not too familiar with that. Really a noob at this. Can you guide me on that as well? @gordon-linoff

Answer (score 0):

I have created the sample case as mentioned below and added the blank rates for two dates i.e. 02-JAN-19 and 04-JAN-19

```
create table test(rate_date date,rate_num integer,fxd_code varchar2(3),
var_code varchar2(3),ratecode varchar2(10), rate float); 

insert into test values('01-JAN-19',1,'USD','EUR','CASH','1.24569');
insert into test values('01-JAN-19',1,'USD','EUR','TRF','1.28795');
insert into test values('01-JAN-19',2,'USD','EUR','CASH','1.28795');
insert into test values('01-JAN-19',1,'USD','GBP','CASH','1.24569');
insert into test values('01-JAN-19',1,'USD','EUR','CASH','1.24569');


insert into test (rate_date,rate_num,fxd_code,var_code,ratecode)values('02-JAN-19',1,'USD','EUR','CASH');
insert into test (rate_date,rate_num,fxd_code,var_code,ratecode)values('02-JAN-19',1,'USD','EUR','TRF');

insert into test values('03-JAN-19',1,'USD','GBP','CASH','1.24579');
insert into test values('03-JAN-19',1,'USD','EUR','CASH','1.24579');

insert into test (rate_date,rate_num,fxd_code,var_code,ratecode)values('04-JAN-19',1,'USD','GBP','CASH');
insert into test (rate_date,rate_num,fxd_code,var_code,ratecode)values('04-JAN-19',1,'USD','EUR','CASH');
```

After that, I made the following query using MERGE which is giving the desired output and same can be converted to UPDATE statement.

```
merge into test A using(select max(rate_date) as recent_date,rate_num,fxd_code,var_code,ratecode,rate from test where rate is not null 
group by rate_num,fxd_code,var_code,ratecode,rate) B on (A.rate_num=B.rate_num and A.fxd_code=B.fxd_code and A.var_code=B.var_code and A.ratecode=B.ratecode and A.rate_date=B.recent_date+1)
when matched then update set A.rate=B.rate where A.rate is null;
```

Before

```
01-JAN-19   1   USD EUR CASH    1.24569
01-JAN-19   1   USD EUR TRF     1.28795
01-JAN-19   2   USD EUR CASH    1.28795
01-JAN-19   1   USD GBP CASH    1.24569
01-JAN-19   1   USD EUR CASH    1.24569
02-JAN-19   1   USD EUR CASH     - 
02-JAN-19   1   USD EUR TRF      - 
03-JAN-19   1   USD GBP CASH    1.24579
03-JAN-19   1   USD EUR CASH    1.24579
04-JAN-19   1   USD GBP CASH     - 
04-JAN-19   1   USD EUR CASH     -
```

After

```
01-JAN-19   1   USD EUR CASH    1.24569
01-JAN-19   1   USD EUR TRF     1.28795
01-JAN-19   2   USD EUR CASH    1.28795
01-JAN-19   1   USD GBP CASH    1.24569
01-JAN-19   1   USD EUR CASH    1.24569
02-JAN-19   1   USD EUR CASH    1.24569
02-JAN-19   1   USD EUR TRF     1.28795
03-JAN-19   1   USD GBP CASH    1.24579
03-JAN-19   1   USD EUR CASH    1.24579
04-JAN-19   1   USD GBP CASH    1.24579
04-JAN-19   1   USD EUR CASH    1.24579
```

I hope this will help you..

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, I do not have admin rights on the DB and won't be able to do a merge.